# How do I prevent my medians from being rounded?

Tags: python, rounding, median

I have code which calculates the median of z-scores, which range from 0 to 1. Python is rounding all these numbers to 0. How would I make sure these numbers are not rounded?

Here's the line of code in which I calculate the medians:

```
gene_medians = GCT_object.data_df.median(axis=1)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import parse_gctoo

def histo_plotter(file, plot_title, ax):
    # read in file as string
    GCT_object = parse_gctoo.parse(file)
    # computing median of rows in data_df
    gene_medians = GCT_object.data_df.median(axis=1)
    unrounded_gm = format(gene_medians, ".7f")
    # making histogram of medians
    print gene_medians'
```

Outcome of .describe:
/Users/eibelman/miniconda2/envs/josh_env/bin/python2.7 /Users/eibelman/Analysis/ComparingMedianGeneExpressionDifCellLines.py
cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A03  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A04  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                    0.072729                   0.078196
std                     2.909874                   3.086884
min                   -18.698500                 -63.467600
25%                    -0.742375                  -0.422625
50%                    -0.030950                   0.205600
75%                     0.656550                   0.885275
max                    29.803200                  27.347300

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A05  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A06  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                    0.036843                   0.002883
std                     2.471833                   2.576255
min                   -17.170500                 -26.433600
25%                    -0.653925                  -0.674250
50%                    -0.081250                  -0.070600
75%                     0.548900                   0.561250
max                    31.356600                  34.249100

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A07  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A08  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                    0.017625                   0.096359
std                     2.012941                   2.671352
min                   -18.651800                 -27.609600
25%                    -0.711400                  -0.730225
50%                    -0.048900                  -0.012100
75%                     0.585300                   0.670100
max                    23.690800                  27.509200

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A09  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A10  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                   -0.024301                  -0.048213
std                     3.317470                   3.431853
min                   -70.184100                 -43.255000
25%                    -0.556725                  -0.916150
50%                     0.009950                  -0.071200
75%                     0.629525                   0.836525
max                    32.083000                  36.831200

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A11  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:A12  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                    0.040646                  -0.013686
std                     2.568421                   3.296173
min                   -17.213400                 -42.862500
25%                    -0.636600                  -0.719425
50%                    -0.032850                  -0.033950
75%                     0.593925                   0.680675
max                    26.524500                  50.334500

cid              ...              CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P15  \
count            ...                             978.000000
mean             ...                              -0.006012
std              ...                               2.564106
min              ...                             -20.208400
25%              ...                              -0.706475
50%              ...                              -0.136300
75%              ...                               0.557025
max              ...                              27.509500

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P16  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P17  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                    0.041587                  -0.001685
std                     1.713974                   3.091669
min                   -12.695900                 -34.948900
25%                    -0.569150                  -0.642050
50%                     0.000000                   0.050800
75%                     0.637700                   0.818025
max                    22.556600                  25.772400

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P18  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P19  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                   -0.019696                   0.061637
std                     2.570132                   2.648487
min                   -33.142900                 -29.076300
25%                    -0.798700                  -0.632600
50%                    -0.057600                   0.048900
75%                     0.588375                   0.679500
max                    30.018900                  30.709400

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P20  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P21  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                    0.026416                  -0.004739
std                     2.616890                   2.135260
min                   -31.187200                 -15.955000
25%                    -0.608050                  -0.732750
50%                     0.008050                  -0.116500
75%                     0.638025                   0.647625
max                    23.348100                  24.229200

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P22  CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P23  \
count                 978.000000                 978.000000
mean                    0.019632                   0.002053
std                     2.581926                   2.356626
min                   -23.168000                 -27.271400
25%                    -0.674500                  -0.683150
50%                    -0.026800                  -0.001000
75%                     0.711800                   0.721400
max                    38.533300                  27.568000

cid    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29:P24
count                 978.000000
mean                   -0.043314
std                     1.704406
min                    -9.464100
25%                    -0.780525
50%                    -0.144250
75%                     0.515325
max                    19.056400

[8 rows x 372 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Try converting the values to float !! Honestly though a bit more context as to how you are calculating these medians is required. If data_df is a pandas dataframe, let us know

Comment: @GauravDhama yes, data_df is a pandas dataframe. By the way, would this work: gene_medians = GCT_object.data_df.median(axis=1)
    unrounded_gm = format(gene_medians, ".7f")

Comment: Can you post a detailed code since this is not a usual behavior from pandas dataframe. I don't think the particular line of code that you have mentioned in your question is the problem.

Comment: The code I added is with the edits I commented above. Before I did not use the format with ".7f"

Comment: Is parse_gctoo a standard module cant find it anywhere on google.

Comment: no it is not standard

Comment: Try this :                                                                                           
 gene_medians = GCT_object.data_df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).median(axis=1)

Comment: I still get a histogram with one bar (since all values are 0)

Comment: Can you post the link to parse_gctoo library if it is uploaded somewhere,im pretty sure `parse_gctoo.parse(file)` is the problematic line here

Comment: sorry not uploaded. But this code worked before for a slightly different file with QNORM values. ZSPCQNORM values range from 0 to 1 and therefore may be rounded

Comment: Precisely, the values are being rounded in the parse object rather than due to the pandas dataframe. You will need to check this method in parse_gctoo

Comment: Let me investigate.

Comment: How can I print out the raw values in the data frame, before taking the median? (So I can check whether it is in fact parce_gctoo that is causing the problem?)

Comment: print (GCT_object.data_df)

Comment: I get a syntax error

Comment: can you post what you get by type(GCT_object.data_df)

Comment: Ok, I've managed to print it out and it's not rounded

Comment: Still need to know the type of the object

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Do you get correct values of the median(~ 50%) if you do a describe on this dataframe i.e df.describe(). Are there a lot of NaN values in your data

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: What is the output of GCT_object.data_df.describe() and are there a lot of missing values in your data?

Comment: I am posting the outcome into the original question

Comment: Last try, let me know if this works,will give you the median : GCT_object.data_df.quantile(q=0.5,axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas data frame (data_df) then you can use median function form numpy package.

```
gene_medians = numpy.median(GCT_object.data_df[[1]])
```

or

```
gene_medians = GCT_object.data_df[[1]].apply(numpy.median)
```

Comment: You can just write- import numpy